# Upload image in div of different size using html5

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, html5-canvas

I want to upload a image into a box (div) which may be rectangle, square , circle or of any shape using html5

Something Like below
[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Do you have some specific code you are working on that you'd like help with?  What exactly is your question?

Comment: i want to use html5 file uploader and place that image into div, html5cnavas/jquery /javascript /css any code

Comment: Reference link http://www.fotor.com/creatives/photo-cards/holiday-cards here you can see same uploading function (code not in html5)

Comment: This might be helpful to take a look at: http://html5demos.com/dnd-upload

Comment: i want image to be fit into box of different shapes, above example  have rectangle shape only..

Answer (score 0):

From your comments I assume that you already know how to upload and draw an image normally, so I will only explain how to get an image "into shape" when drawing it.

Take a look at the [compositing settings](https://developer.mozilla.org/samples/canvas-tutorial/6_1_canvas_composite.html) of the 2d context. These allow you to use a path or an image to perform masking on a canvas.

1. draw your image to your canvas in the desired size
2. [create a path](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D#Paths) which marks the edges of the shape you want to "cut out". 3. set `context.fillColor` to something solid without an alpha transparency when you don't already did so
3. set `context.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-in'`
4. use `context.fillPath` to draw the path in destination-in mode. This erases everything outside of the path and keeps everything inside the path.
5. set context.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-over'` to restore the normal drawing behavior.